# How to change my query to keep only one record per Item?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

My code below works, but I am getting more than 1 record per Item_TAG which I dont want to. I tried changing ESP_Facturacao.[1a_mesAno] as Data, to MAX(ESP_Facturacao.[1a_mesAno]) as Data;
It did not work. Anyone has a suggestion?

```
SELECT
ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID,
ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID,
ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno] AS Data,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_Faturado] AS Valor,
'1 a' AS Tarefa,
'1' AS Control,
'1' AS Estado,
ESP_SubTipo.Descrição AS SubTipo,
ESP_Unidade.Descricao AS Unidade,
ESP_Facturacao.ID

FROM ESP_Unidade INNER JOIN (((ESP_TAG LEFT JOIN ESP_Facturacao ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Facturacao.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN (ESP_SubTipo INNER JOIN ESP_Fisico ON ESP_SubTipo.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID) ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN ESP_Administrativas ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Administrativas.ESP_Tag_ID) ON ESP_Unidade.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG) Not In (SELECT ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
FROM ESP_Facturacao
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null)))) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Novo_Pos_2010)=True));
```

Comment: All you are doing by changing `AS Data` is changing the alias for that particular column. Are you sure there is only one record stored per item? What is after the `Union All`?

Comment: I changed it to MAX. After union all there is similar code, for different controls. The point is I have duplicate records for the same ITEM_TAG and I want only one.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from what you have posted - we can only see half the query and no table data. Also, Union queries specifically join `like` queries to each other and as such if each half of the query finds `item1` for example, you will have multiple results.

Comment: forget the union . imagine its not there.

Comment: If I have just this query, and I have two lines with the same ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG, what do I need to change to only have one record instead of two?

Comment: Is ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG a key field? Are the 2 item in the table with the same ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG? Try adding `DISTINCT` after you `Select` do you now only get one?

Comment: Basically this table has data on payments per equipment, ITEM TAG is the equipment "name", and I want to know how many equipments have never had any payments, thats why i dont want to have the same item tag showing up twice.